# Unlist update from update list openSuse

Tags: linux, opensuse

Is there a way to stop openSuse from trying to install a particular update? Everytime I have new updates, it tries to install kernel-desktop-3.11.10-25.1 (x64) along with a newer version (currently 3.19). If I leave it checked, the installation fails.. and if I uncheck it, next time I have updates this particular update reappears. It makes no sense to install it since I have a newer version available, so I would like to remove it from my recommended updates.

EDIT: It is tangential to the question at hand, but the error currently displayed if I try to install the update is "There is no update candidate for kernel-desktop-3.19.0-2.1.g1133f88.x86_64".

Comment: have you tried `zypper al kernel-desktop`? (you can specify version numbers too)

Comment: @llua would I still receive other kernel updates if I lock that specific version? If so, it might just be what I'm looking for

Comment: What do you mean by other kernel updates? Are you talking about would you still be able to install the newest version of a xen kernel, debug kernel, or default kernel? If that is the case then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `zypper addlock <packagename>`

Add a package lock. Specify packages to lock by exact name or by a glob pattern using '*' and '?' wildcard characters.